# How to install desktop environments such as kubuntu and gnome safely

Tags: unity

Help! Last time I tried to install desktop environments I broke Unity! I want some variety, but I am too scared! I don't want to reinstall ubuntu again! Please help!

I want to install extra interfaces without breaking unity or being able to fix everything with the terminal, should I break it.

EDIT: Guys, I need a failsafe, should I put something I don't like on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run the following commands to install a gnome-shell background.

1. `sudo su -` #will ask for your system password to become the superuser
2. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next` #press enter again
3. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging` #press enter again
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions` #after this installation gnome-shell configuration menu will come and you can choose between gdm and lightdm options of which gdm has a different login appearance while lightdm has the one similar to unity. So better choose gdm here.

> 

You are done.

You can always switch between gdm and lightdm with the following command:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`     # here select gdm or lightdm and press enter.

Comment: I've decided to stick to unity for now, but thanks anyway!